# mysql_version.h not found when building application with mysql++

Tags: c++, mysql, mysql++

I want to connect to my MySQL database with c++ with the mysql++ library (wrapper) in linux (ubuntu 12.04). I installed mysql via the xampp for linux, but also tried it with `sudo apt-get istall mysql-server`. I got the mysql++ lib with `sudo apt-get install libmysqlclient15-dev`.

The include statement `include <mysql++/mysql++.h>` gave no warning, but when I'm trying to build my application, this is the compilation error:

`In file included from /usr/include/mysql++/connection.h:38:0,
                 from /usr/include/mysql++/mysql++.h:56,
                 from /home/bert/Documents/QtProjecten/FGBG/modules/server/mysqldb.h:6,
                 from /home/bert/Documents/QtProjecten/FGBG/modules/server/mysqldb.cpp:1:
/usr/include/mysql++/common.h:131:28: fatal error: mysql_version.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.`

Indeed there is no `mysql_version.h` in the `/usr/include/mysql++` directory. Does anybody have a clue what this means? I almost couldn't find any documentation on this matter and I even tried to copy the `mysql_version.h`-file from `/usr/include/mysql` to `/usr/include/mysql++`.

Edit:

- I have two mysql++ dirs in my file system: `/usr/local/include/mysql++` and `/usr/include/mysql++`. Could this be a problem?
- I changed `#include <mysql++/mysql++.h>` to `</usr/include/mysql++/mysql++.h>`, didn't work.
- When I change the GXX flags (`-DMYSQLPP_MYSQL_HEADERS_BURIED` or `-I/usr/include/mysql`) in my Cmakelist, it doesn't recognize the `mysqlpp` namespace anymore.

Here is the code of my header file:

```
#ifndef MYSQLDB_H
#define MYSQLDB_H

#include <mysql++/mysql++.h>

class MySQLDB{

public:
MySQLDB();
~MySQLDB();
bool open(std::string dbname, std::string hostname, std::string username, std::string password);
mysqlpp::StoreQueryResult query(std::string sql);
bool close();

private:
mysqlpp::Connection conn;
};
#endif
```

Answer (score 3):

Check if you can link mysqlpp namespace using,

```
dpkg -L libmysql++-dev
```

If yes, i.e. if you have libmysqlpp.a, link it using -**lmysqlpp** as following,

```
 g++ sm_cpp.cpp -o test -I/usr/include/mysql++ -I/usr/include/mysql -lmysqlpp
```

It will work.  The linker searches a standard list of directories for the library, which is actually a file named liblibrary.a.  The linker then uses this file as if it had been specified precisely by name. [include `<mysql++.h>` - No such file or directory](http://www.experts-exchange.com/Programming/Editors_IDEs/Q_25120724.html)

Answer (score 1):

mysql_version.h is part of mysql package, not mysqlpp package. Just include /usr/include/mysql or usr/local/include/mysql [ depends on where you istalled mysql dev files ] into your IDE. Easy solution (:

Answer (score 1):

Compile with the `-DMYSQLPP_MYSQL_HEADERS_BURIED` flag, or include the mysql directory directly. I.e. try one of the following:

```
g++ test.cpp -o test -DMYSQLPP_MYSQL_HEADERS_BURIED

g++ test.cpp -o test -I/usr/include/mysql/
```

Both of these worked for me.

More information can be found in [this bug report](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=702417).

Answer (score 0):

If you build your own package it might be helpful to uninstall all related dev package from your system (mysql++).

Comment: Hi, please look at my edit. Do you have any more suggestions on this matter? Thanks